# Is it possible to generate usable electricity from the motion or magnetic field of the Earth?

Tags: electricity, earth, magnetic-fields, renewable-energy

Let me start by saying that my knowledge of physics is almost nil (only high school level and I pretty much forgot everything) so bear with me, if I am asking naive questions the answers of which may be obvious to you.

My question is twofold:

1. Is it possible to use the motion of the planet or its magnetic field to extract an electric current efficiently?
2. If yes, how much electricity could be generated? Enough to power a toaster? A house? A city?

Comment: I don't think [20-60 micro Teslas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field) would do much good for power generation...

Comment: Elaborating upon Crazy Buddy comment: the EMF (voltage) is given as the time derivative of the magnetic flux. The magnetic flux is 20-60 microweber per each squared meter (Weber would have a birthday today). If the flux reverts the sign each 3.14 seconds, then you have 20-60 microvolts per each squared meter. So of course that a quickly rotating 1km x 1km wire can get dozens of volts. But what's the point? You can easily get stronger magnetic fields "for free" so the weak geomagnetic field is useless. The wire won't keep on rotating indefinitely - it will slow down as it extracts the energy.

Comment: The geomagnetic field at huge distances - like on Venus or Mars - is completely negligible. If you goal were to extract energy from the magnetic field of Earth by weakening it, let me mention that at 20-60 micro tesla is about $B^2/2\mu_0$ which is about $10^{-10}/10^{-6}$ or $10^{-4}$ joules per cubic meter. Even if you multiply it by thousands of kilometers, you only get hundreds of joules per squared meter. Even the complete destruction of the geomagnetic field (not really possible in practice) would only give you a modest amount of energy - once.

Comment: Tidal power plants basically generate their power from the rotation of the Earth.